# Multiple databases with Spring Boot MongoDB Repositories dynamically

Tags: angularjs, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I needed to modify my Spring-Boot app to manage dynamically  instances of the Mongo driver dynamically. In my app  Spring Boot MongoDB Repositories is  already configured, now acc. to new requirement we want to implement sass (dynamically tenant) in which one is master db and another db dynamically select db. Now problem is that how to configured the spring Boot another MongoDB Repositories dynamically in app when we select the any tenant.
Eg: Suppose 5 tenant select any of them dynamically inside the app, the other DB randomly selected

Comment: Is the other DB randomly selected or is it something like for customer X we have DB x, so if a user logs in for example spring will see he belongs to company X and spring will use DB x?

Comment: yes,  the other DB randomly selected with Spring Boot MongoDB Repositories @SvenHakvoort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        DyanamicRepository dyanmicRepositry=CustomMongoDbMongoRepositoryFactoryClass.getRepository(Pass_DyanamicRepository.class, Pass_DynamicDataBaseName);
        dyanmicRepositry.save(dealer);

        ******************************************


        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.CustomConversions;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory;
        import com.mongodb.Mongo;



        public final class CustomMongoDbMongoRepositoryFactoryClass {

            static final Map<String,Object> LOCK_OBJECT=new HashMap<>();                
            private static final Map<String,MongoOperations> MONGOOP_CACHE=new HashMap<>();
            private static final Map<String,Map<String,Object>> REPOS_CACHE=new HashMap<>();                        
            public static MongoOperations getMongoOperations(Vendor vendor){                                

            String database =vendor.getVendorName().replaceAll("[\\s]", "");                                        
            MongoOperations mongoOperations=MONGOOP_CACHE.get(database);
            if(mongoOperations==null){
                    Mongo mongo=ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(Mongo.class);
                    CustomConversions mappingMongoConverter=ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(CustomConversions.class);

                    MongoTemplate mm = new MongoTemplate(mongo, database);                      
                    MappingMongoConverter mmc = (MappingMongoConverter)mm.getConverter();           
                    mmc.setCustomConversions(mappingMongoConverter);
                    mmc.afterPropertiesSet();
                    mongoOperations=  mm;               
                    MONGOOP_CACHE.put(database,mongoOperations);
            }

            return mongoOperations;


        }

        public static synchronized <T extends Serializable> T getRepository(Class<T> type,Vendor vendor){

            if(vendor.getId()=="") {
                return ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(type);
            }               

            String database =vendor.getVendorName().replaceAll("[\\s]", "");
            Map<String,Object> repos=REPOS_CACHE.get(database);
            if(repos==null) {
                repos=new HashMap<>();
                REPOS_CACHE.put(database,repos);

            }                       
            if(repos.containsKey(type.getName())) {
                System.out.println("Get "+type.getName()+" Repo in ::: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start) +"ms");
                return (T) repos.get(type.getName());
            }           
            MongoOperations mongoOperations=getMongoOperations(vendor);         

            MongoRepositoryFactory bean=new MongoRepositoryFactory(mongoOperations);

            T repo=bean.getRepository(type);             

            repos.put(type.getName(), repo);


            return repo;
        }
```